# I am taking an array input from user and want to find the second largest element in python

Tags: python

```
 print("Enter an array of numbers: ")
 a=[]                       
 for x in input().split():   
    a.append(x)

a.remove(max(a))
print(max(a))

output:

Enter an array of numbers: 
10 150 30 20
20
```

I also tried sorting but it also didn't work

```
print("Enter an array of numbers: ")
 a=[]                       
for x in input().split():   
    a.append(x)

a.sort()
print(a)
print(a[len(a)-2])

output:
 Enter an array of numbers: 
 10 150 20 30
 ['10', '150', '20', '30']
 20
```

Took input via map function still not working
I can iterate each and every number and can find out but is there any other way?

Comment: "It did not work" is not an acceptable description of an error. Try again.

Comment: You aren't casting the numbers to `int`, hence the error.

Comment: Well since it's not giving desired output I used 'not working'

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil How to do that?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I am completely new to python so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the numbers are in string format. Here is an easy solution.

```
a = ['5', '10', '2', '3']
b = [int(c) for c in a]
b.sort()
result = b[-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make integers forom strings. Without it you sorting array [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).
 To convert, use `int()`:

```
print("Enter an array of numbers: ")
a=[]                       

for x in input().split():   
    a.append(int(x))

a.sort()
print(a)
print(a[-2])
```

Also see the last line - it is more pythonic way to write `a[-2]` instead of `a[len(a)-2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `map` to cast all the input numbers to `int`. Since `map` returns a generator instance, you need to consume it by calling it in `list()` or `sorted()`. Something like below.

```
>>> my_array = sorted(map(int, input("Enter an array of numbers: ").split()))
Enter an array of numbers: 10 150 20 30
>>> print(my_array[-2])
30
```

Array slicing also accepts negative integers, i.e. -1 stands for the last element, -2 is the 2nd last, etc.

Comment: I was using sort() with map and it kept throwing error

Comment: Yes, because `map` produces a generator instance and not a `list` that `.sort()` expects.